# Is there a more efficient way to satisfy project dependencies than pip?

Tags: python, linux, django, dependencies, pip

I work on a system and the hosting guys don't want to use an install script that uses pip. Now we have a large pip requirements file that install the dependencies. Is there any other way to do it than using pip? Can it be done using `yum` or `apt-get` ? We are using Linux.

Comment: It has never occured to me that somebody allows the use of a system-wide change with apt-get but not pip.

Comment: can you use easy_install ?

Comment: Wow, your hosting people would rather allow apt-get to install all sorts of random software throughout the system, than allow the focused installation of only Python libraries within a virtualenv? Get new hosting people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For god's sake, please do not fall back to using the distribution's package manager just because your hosting guys do not understand what `pip`+`virtualenv` is good for.

Python packages in Linux distribution repositories are often outdated and may come with quirks that other Python package authors did not plan for. This is especially true for Python packages with compiled code. If a documentation tells you that a certain dependency should be obtained directly from PyPI via pip, then you better follow that requirement. Convince your hosting guys to use the right tools, namely `pip` combined with `virtualenv`. The latter will create an isolated environment and make sure that the system will stay clean (really, nobody needs to do a `sudo pip install`, which probably is the thing your hosting guys are afraid of).